# How do I write a variable that includes multiple values and commas to a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

How do I write a variable that includes multiple values and commas to a CSV file?
for example the variable might hold `jimmy,5,250,james` and I want to write this to a CSV file then start a new line and write the next batch of variables in the loop again in the same fashion.

> outFile = open('outputfile.csv','w')
>    csvFile_out = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter=',')   csvFile_out.writerows(valuesvariable)

Comment: Use SSV: Semicolon-separated values. ;) Alternatively, replace commas with something else when writing, then put them back when reading.

Comment: Is the variable you have a string? If so - just write it as a line...

Comment: There is really no standard csv format. Meaning there is no standrad way of doing this. I would opt for SSV, or encapsulating the variables with hyphens, allowing them to be treated as a string by some parsers

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data looked something like this (*I'm assuming this is the kind of data you want to deal with since you mentioned multiple values*):

```
data = [
    ("jimmy", 5, 250, "james",)
    ("bobby", 7, 270, "mark",)
]
```

You can simply iterate through the data in a simple "for loop" and write "comma separated" values out in each line:

```
with open("data.csv", "w") as f:
    for values in data:
        f.write("{0:s}\n".format(",".join(map(str, values))))
```

Alternatively (*and recommended*) you can use the Python `csv` module; specifically the [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) class like this:

```
import csv

with open("data.csv", "wb") as fd:
    csvfile = csv.writer(fd)

    for values in data:
        csvfile.writerow(values)
```

You can of course shorten this by using `csv.writer.writerows()`:

```
import csv

with open("data.csv", "wb") as fd:
    csvfile = csv.writer(fd)
    csvfile.writerows(data)
```

Comment: I used this and the output was going down the csv file diagonally. When i print the variable it is fine but when I go to print it, it fails

Comment: "When I go to print it; it's fine but when I print it it fails". This makes no sense to me whatsoever.

Comment: @user2736517 do you actually have a string or another sequence such as list/tuple? It'd help if you showed how you're acquiring/setting your variable in your original post - please free to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30369641/edit) your question to clarify the comments you've been asked - we're trying to help - if we don't have sufficient information that we've kindly asked you for - we can't.

Comment: sorry mate, had a typo. What i meant is when I got to write the variable it fails, how can I post my code on here?

Comment: 'code' outFile = open('outputfile.csv','w') 
    csvFile_out = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter=',')
    csvFile_out.writerows(valuesvariable) 'code'

Answer (score 0):

For a variable that holds multiple values I would use an array and loop through that with a foreach loop or something similar. That way every value stays properly seperated regardless of punctuation.